# jquery datatable doesn't show buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm loading data into html table using jquery:

```
        function loaddata() {
        var table = $('#dataTable1').DataTable({
            "buttons": ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis'],
            "paging": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "responsive": true,
            'ajax': {
                "type": "GET",
                "url": "http://localhost:5000/getallworkers",
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    var return_data = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        return_data.push({
                            'IDRadnik': json[i].IDRadnik,
                            'Ime': json[i].Ime,
                            'Prezime': json[i].Prezime
                        })
                    }
                    return return_data;
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { 'data': 'IDRadnik' },
                { 'data': 'Ime' },
                { 'data': 'Prezime' }
            ],
            "buttons": ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis']
        });

        table.buttons().container().appendTo('#dataTable1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
    }
```

Problem here is that buttons are not displayed. But if I do only this:

```
 function loaddata() {
 var table = $('#dataTable1').DataTable({
            "buttons": ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis']});
 
 table.buttons().container().appendTo('#dataTable1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
 }
```

buttons are there... Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option and add `B` for Buttons.

```js
var table = $('#dataTable1').DataTable({
    "dom": "lBftrip"
});
```